# Управление устройством ввода

Tags: клавиатура, мышь

Есть макросные клавиатуры и мышки, которые имеют свой софт для написания макросов.

Как они взаимодействуют с приложениями / устройством ?

`SendInput`, `mouse_event` и тому подобное - хукаются защитой в играх, при этом я не видел ни одной игры которая хукала посылы от макросной клавиатуры или мышки.

**В чем секрет?**

Comment: Потому что с точки зрения системы нет никакого перехвата. ПО клавомышы само внутри себя реализует перехват  и отправляет системе его результат

Comment: Только, видимо, не ПО "клавомыши", а ее драйвер.